# How to mark JSESSIONID secure in tomcat?

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, jsessionid

I want to mark my `JSESSIONID` cookie generated by tomcat(version 8) as secure. im using `java 12`...

So far i have tried

1. in tomcat `web.xml` file, i have added

```
    <cookie-config>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
    <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
```

in session-config section

2. tried, `cookie.setSecure(true)` in my `servlet`

both not working.. any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 flag should be maintain to avoid Session cookies hijacking(HttpOnly, Secure)**

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=T8zK7hcII6iNgA; Expires=Wed, 21 May 2018 07:28:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
```

For Servlet 3.0 the configuration as

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
      <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
      <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>

i have already tried this on tomcat web.xml... still cookies are not secure

can you please explain more about this ->
"Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=T8zK7hcII6iNgA; Expires=Wed, 21 May 2018 07:28:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure"

Comment: That the http header in details

Comment: Share your web.xml then that will help to understand the issue more